# Why do I need jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js after a successful jQuery upgrade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-migrate

I am done upgrading jQuery from 1.3.1 to 1.12.4. Everything is working correctly and I am ready to remove jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js because I was only using it for debugging purposes during the upgrade process.

When I remove jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js from the `<head>` section of my website, the page does not work properly anymore. Something breaks in the JavaScript/jQuery. I was reading https://blog.jquery.com/2016/05/19/jquery-migrate-1-4-1-released-and-the-path-to-jquery-3-0/ trying to find information about it, and this is something I found:

> Remove the Migrate 1.x plugin and ensure the page still works properly without it loaded.

Why do I need jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js after a successful jQuery upgrade? I thought it was only a "behind the scenes" script for debugging purposes exclusively, not to maintain any jQuery/JavaScript functionality.

Comment: Sounds like you did not fix everything if it breaks without it. What are the errors are you seeing when you remove it?

Comment: So, what is going wrong? What is not working and what is in the console? Maybe that could shed a hint on why the page doesn't work as expected anymore

Comment: the Migrate plugin is supposed to throw console.log errors if it encounters jQuery code that is likely to break in the newer version of jQuery.  When it was installed did you get any errors?

Comment: jQuery Migrate's purpose is to allow you to use deprecated features while still using a newer version of the library.  It's not just a "behind the scenes" thing.  It will log when you are using deprecated features but the intent is to allow you to use newer libraries without removing code that has been removed from the newer libraries.

Comment: @epascarello I see for example: "JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated". That is odd though, because the source of that error is jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js:45 and that is the jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js file, not that I am using jQuery.browser in my code.

Comment: @Icepickle Everything is working after the upgrade but in the console I see things such as: "jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js:45 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.size() is deprecated; use the .length property". But I cannot find jQuery.fn.size() in my source code. When I search for it, I only find it in line 377 of jquery-migrate-1.4.js, but that is not really my source code, that is the jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js file I am using to assist me in the upgrading process.

Comment: @JasonSperske Yes, it threw errors when it was installed, for example "jQuery.browser is deprecated", but I removed that from my JavaScript code and I am not using it anymore. Nonetheless, I still see "JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated" and the only place where I can find it is in the jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js file.

Comment: @stephen.vakil I thought the intent was to help you in the debugging process to identify deprecated code and replace it with new modern code. I did not know it was a tool to maintain old code working synchronously with new code.

Comment: It's kind of both, the console.logs help you clean up while the workarounds let you maintain functionality until you cleaned up your code.

Comment: You should be looking for size().....not the full string... and $.browser is probably the other thing to look at....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The misunderstanding that is tripping you up at the moment is that the purpose of `jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js` is to install a few backward focused workarounds to make early jQuery code work in the more up to date jQuery while also complaining into your console.log so you can fix it.  It is not actually changing your code.  A couple of pointers to help you migrate based on your comments:

> I see for example: "JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated". That is odd though, because the source of that error is jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js:45 and that is the jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js file, not that I am using jQuery.browser in my code.

The line doing the logging is in the `jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js` so the error appears to point to that file, however, the line calling `jQuery.browser` might be in a plugin you are loading (this was common in early jQuery days where people wrote browser-specific hacks)  You can try and search for `.browser` in all of your linked `.js` files (even the minified ones) to at least isolate the plugin and then try to find alternatives.

> I see things such as: "jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js:45 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.size() is deprecated; use the .length property". But I cannot find jQuery.fn.size() in my source code.

The approach of `jQuery.fn.size()` might show up in your code like this:

```
$('li.items').size()
```

`jQuery.fn` is just the object name of a jQuery element's functions.  Because your jQuery object is based on a jQuery selector you wrote it might be hard to search for it, instead look for something like `.size()` and if it shows up to the right of a jQuery selector then try and replace it with just `.length` (no parentheses, as `length` is just a property).

If you have other questions you are probably better off posting them as new questions so they can get more direct and generally helpful answers.

Comment: When I see `JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated` in the console, it points to this file: `jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js`. I searched for `$.browser` and I can see that it is used in some of my plugins. Why is it that when I see in the console `JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated`, it does not point to the files containing the plugins where the deprecated `$.browser` is used? It would be more useful than pointing to `jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js`. I already know and it is obvious that if JQMIGRATE is complaining into my console, it is because the `jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js` utility was used.

Comment: The information you are looking for would be in the `stack trace` but this information is not available to JavaScript code (you can throw an exception and the browser will build a `stack trace` for debugging, but you can't write JS code that inspects that at runtime) so this is just the next best alternative.

Comment: See this image: https://imgur.com/a/uAThZ Apparently it is already telling me where $.browse is used in my plugins. Is that the `stack trace` you are referring to that is not available to JavaScript code?

Comment: And now I just learned about `console.trace` That is going to come in handy :)

Comment: Apparently you could can add browser detection back into jQuery http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2012/08/14/jquery-1-8-and-browser-detection/

Comment: Interesting. But I guess to simplify things using https://modernizr.com is the recommended way to do browser detection.